# How to update joined table in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

as you can see here : 
    [image]

I'm trying to update `SpectableGenreTableAdapter` but as it is a joined table between `Spectacle` and `Genre`, I can't use

```
this.spectacleGenreBindingSource.AddNew();
this.spectacleGenreBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.SpectacleGenreTableAdapter.Update().
```

So what is the way to do it? I've been trying to use a `dataTableManager` but I can't manage to do it this way too.

Comment: Your joins look "odd" should the Genre table not have a relationship with Spectacle Genre instead of direcetly with Spectacle?

Comment: I'm not sure, I needed a row from genre in my spectacle table, so I created SpectacleGenreTable.